# In a Dictionary<string,Attachment>, is the Attachment a reference or value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, vsto, outlook-2007

I'm asking because classes tend to be passed by reference, but I'm not sure in the case of Dictionary

Comment: If `Attachment` is a class, then yes it's a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. Reference types (`class`) are passed by reference. Value types (`struct`) are passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Attachment is a COM interface, so it is very much a reference type. Even though you are accessing it via the Value property.